# I'm not am getting a result back from a query that I should be getting a result back from

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails-jquery-autocomplete to fill in a `cabinet_name` in a form like this:

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag :cabinet_name, '', cabinets_autocomplete_cabinet_name_path %>
```

Along with the other data, here are the params being passed to the device controller:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"/0yFGrlBy0y+2ksTkQN50Dmfpw7ZWBKsO2zswAigJZI=",
"device"=>{"name"=>"Test dropdown",
"device_model_id"=>"621",
"device_unit_count"=>"1",
 "position"=>"1",
 "row_id"=>"1"},
 "cabinet_name"=>"0055-COMM-ANNEX-C3",
 "commit"=>"Create Device"}
```

As you can see there is definitely a `cabinet_name` being passed in the `device` hash.  Here is the code in the `devices_controller`:

```
def create
  if params[:cabinet_name]
    @cabinet = Cabinet.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:cabinet_name])
  else
    @cabinet = Cabinet.find(params[:device][:cabinet_id])
  end
...
 @device.row_id = @cabinet.row_id
```

Here's the query that runs according to command line output, notice the:

```
  ←[1m←[35mCabinet Load (2.9ms)←[0m  SELECT `cabinets`.* FROM `cabinets` WHERE (
name LIKE '0055-COMM-ANNEX-C3' )
```

Here's the manual query and result I ran that shows a result of one cabinet record:

```
mysql> select `cabinets`.* from `cabinets` where name like '0055-COMM-ANNEX-C3'


---------------+
| id   | name               | row_id | data_center_id | cabinet_type_id | creat
d_at          | updated_at          | row_name | cabinet_name | capacity_used |
not_cabinet | grid_location_name | grid_location_id | is_rack | alias_name
   | room_id | mark_review | mark_validated | mark_audit | last_audit_note | ma
k_deleted | purpose | total_power_kpm | total_max_power_kpm | total_heat_btu |
otal_max_heat_btu | total_heat_kpm | total_max_heat_kpm | total_spec_ratings |
ean_efficiency |

------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-
---------------+
| 1389 | 0055-COMM-ANNEX-C3 |   NULL |              3 |               1 | 2012-
1-05 21:55:23 | 2012-11-21 16:21:34 | C3       | C3           |             2 |
       NULL | C3                 |             2287 |       0 | 0055-COMM-ANNEX
C3 |       4 |        NULL |           NULL |       NULL | NULL            |
     NULL | NULL    |              42 |                  64 |            200 |
              280 |              8 |                 10 |                  0 |
          NULL |

------------------+----------------+--------------------+--------------------+-
---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's the error that the browser throws stating now Cabinet was selected:

```
undefined method `row_id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x5845368>
```

Please provide some help if you understand the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you're calling `@device.row_id`, where `@device` is `Cabinet.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:cabinet_name])`. If you want the first cabinet where the cabinet name is like `params[:cabinet_name]`, change that to:

```
Cabinet.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:cabinet_name]).first
```

Then you can call `row_id` on it as you expect. Essentially you're calling `row_id` on an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, rather than on an instance of `Cabinet`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    @cabinet = Cabinet.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:cabinet_name])
```

That line returns a collection of results, so when you're trying to grab the id from the collection, your code is bombing out.

You could do something like:

```
    @cabinet = Cabinet.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:cabinet_name]).first
```

to grab the first result.

Answer (score 1):

`.where` returns an `Array` not a single `Object`, you are expecting it to return a single `Object`, and you are matching the complete string so there is no need use `like` if that is the case,

So Either

assuming cabinet names are unique and you need a complete match you should use the following

```
@cabinet = Cabinet.find_by_name(params[:cabinet_name])
```

OR

or if you expect multiple results than you need to get whatever result you want to work on if you want the first one

```
@cabinet = Cabinet.where("name LIKE ? ", params[:cabinet_name]).first
```